# How to hide save dropdown in titlebar of Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using a version of Word that is part of the Office 365 suite.  There is a widget in the titlebar of a document's window that is new to me.  I find it annoying, because it takes away from the amount of the titlebar I can safely click on or drag.

The widget is to the right of the quick access toolbar, it displays the file's name and saved state.  The widget is also a dropdown that, when expanded, shows more info about the file including version history.

What do you call that widget?  Is there an option to hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To move the window you can *still* grab on this or the search area or the sign-in area , I.e. most of the title bar, but, for more "clear" space, about your only option is File>Options>"Collapse the Microsoft Search box by default".

Answer (score 0):

That's simply the file name and I don't think there would be a way to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is called the Title Bar is because it has the name of te document. This is not optional.

You can, though, move the Quick Access Toolbar under the Ribbon where there is more room for buttons.

You can also hide the title bar along with the Ribbon, QAT, and Status Bar using the [AutoHide the Ribbon option](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/minimizing-ribbon-autohiding-ribbon-toggling/5706d1c8-8e59-4514-bc0c-a091990c667f).